# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." Facing this issue

Tags: xamarin, exception, xamarin.forms, maui

I have used MAUI preview .and VS 2022 .When the application is run and used all functionality and press system back button and cloes the app.After cloesing the app I'm try to oepn the app that time

```
"{Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
"
```

Is Occure on my mainActivity page .

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try
        {
            // TEXTVIEW

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);                           
            initFontScale();
            Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            UserDialogs.Init(this);
            //Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

How to resolve this error .

Comment: Do you know what version of .NET MAUI you're using? Seems like this was reported and should be fixed for preview 11 (and 12): https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3511 Which VS2022 have you installed? Did you update it to the latest?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thank you Boss. I have update preview version 1.1 To 2.0 and the problem is resolve. But my Application UI littel bit disturb.

Comment: One problem at a time ;) I'll add it as an answer and would be grateful if you could accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this was reported and according to the comment in there, this should be fixed for preview 11+: github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3511 Which VS2022 have you installed?

Installing Visual Studio 2022 v17.1 Preview 2 should give you .NET MAUI Preview 11 which should resolve the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue in preview 12.